# Spring Cloud Function - Form Data/Multipart File?

Tags: java, spring, lambda, serverless, spring-cloud-function

I am creating a Spring Cloud Function that I want to give two inputs, an id and a Multipart file (CSV file) but I am having trouble.

If I choose to send a post with a multipart file the function won't recognise this and gives an error like `Failed to determine input for function call with parameters:`

With the Postman request being this:

[image]

```
@Bean
    public Function<MultipartFile, String> uploadWatchlist() {
        return body -> {
            try {
                    return service.convert(body);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried using something more akin to Spring MVC like a request entity object but no luck.

The backup I have (other than Python haha) will be using the binary data post so it will just be a string that has the contents of the file which does work, but requires me to append the id inside to each row of the csv which is a bit messy.

There are other solutions but trying to get this working as Java lambdas are what we want to try and use as first choice.

The infrastructure will be to fix up a manual file upload/verification process that is tedious at the moment and looks like: postman -> load balancer -> lambda -> ecs

The postman/load balancer part will be replaced in future. Ideally have the lambda sorted in Java taking in a file and id.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I believe this issue has been addressed in spring-cloud-function and is available with the latest releases.